# Is there any Person to Person payment service I can integrate into my marketplace, whereby I can also take a percentage for myself?

Tags: paypal, payment, paypal-adaptive-payments, amazon-pay

I think PayPal does something like this with Adaptive Payments. Is there anything else?

I have a freelance marketplace and I'd like to allow the employer to send payments to all his workers in one swoop. I'd also like to receive a percentage.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use Chained payments (Paypal Adaptive Payments API). Chained payments enable a sender to send a single payment to a primary receiver. The primary receiver keeps part of the payment and pays secondary receivers the remainder.

https://cms.paypal.com/es/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APIntro